# How to handle form values when values submitting after session timed out?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, session, session-cookies

I am using spring boot and I have forms throughout the application.

Let's say application user is filling out the form after completed the form user take a break for a while then session timed out. User returns the form again and pressed submit button. Application redirected user to login page and user logged in again, problem occurred in here.

How should I handle this situation? 
How should application behave in here :

1- Should the application show filled out the form ?

2- Should the application submit the form values then show success/error message.